# What is the speed penalty for Chainmail?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, armor

Does it do like -1 to speed? What is the speed penalty for using Chainmail?

Comment: Welcome to the site! When formulating questions, it helps to put in some background information to help provide a more specific answer. Why are you getting a penalty for wearing Chainmail?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how this Q&A site works.  The probable reason for seeing that "-1" (a down vote) can be seen if you mouse over the down vote button: the text reads 'this question does not show any research effort' ... the [how to ask a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) notes at the [help] are aids to asking a good question here.  As I found out when I first began to participate here, there is a certain preferred approach to questions and answers here.  Stick around, as I did, and please enjoy this fine Q&A site.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the Player's Handbook?  If not, have you taken a look at [the basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf)?  Pages 44 and 45 cover the basics of armor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Heavy Armor. Heavier armor interferes with the wearer’s ability to move quickly, stealthily, and freely. If the Armor table shows “Str 13” or “Str 15” in the Strength column for an armor type, the armor reduces the wearer’s speed by 10 feet unless the wearer has a Strength score equal to or higher than the listed score. - *PHB*, p144

Chain Mail is Heavy Armor, with a Strength Requirement of 13. If the character is at least STR13, they take no speed modifier for the weight of the armor.

Also...

> If you wear armor that you lack proficiency with, you have disadvantage on any ability check, saving throw, or attack roll that involves Strength or Dexterity,
>   and you can’t cast spells. - *ibid*

Some armors, including all heavy armors, impose a disadvantage on *Stealth* checks, regardless of proficiency. There's no way around it for heavy armor. For medium armor, the *Medium Armor Master* feat allows you to ignore the stealth penalty, among other benefits.

> Heavy armor doesn’t let you add your Dexterity modifier to your Armor Class, but it also doesn’t penalize you if your Dexterity modifier is negative. - *PHB*, p145.

And lastly... Dwarves don't care. They only have a speed of 25, but it's unaffected by heavy armor (*PHB*, p20). It doesn't get them out of the penalties for lack of proficiency, though.

Comment: Oh my character is a Dwarf so i guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: @jeff As I said in my Question comment, that's good info to provide up front. Also, please note that while your speed isn't affected, your Dex/STR ability checks, saving throws, and attack rolls are (as T.J.L. said.)